# How to write an algorithm in Perl to read data from two files match and print the query

Tags: algorithm, perl

I am in a difficult situation writing an algorithm for a task. Every question I ask here I am learning something new and thanks for that.

I have to read a text file (a table contains an ID and a name) and I have to match them with another file which has the same ID and name.

I want to write a program in Perl to print out the result which will match the first table with the second, and  print only the matching ID, name, sub-ID and date (last two fields from the second table).

Can anyone help me out with this?

This is what I already tried.

```
#!/bin/env perl

use strict;  
use warnings;  
use autodie;  

use Data::Dumper;  

# Create a file handle for the input file 
my $fname = 'secondtable.txt';  
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $fname);  

# print header  
my $cname = readline $fh;  
print $cname;  

# # print rows  
while ( my $line = readline $fh ) {
  chomp $line;
  print "$line\n";
}
```

Comment: This is an imprecise problem description.  If you explain with more care, you're more likely to get a useful answer. Sample data will allow people to give you a working solution. And the rules of SO require that you explain what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  It sounds straight-forward enough, to the extent you've explained it.  Read the first file and stash the information in a hash table of some sort.  Read the second file, and when the identification information matches, print the line.  Show us your code and we can help more; until then, there's not much we can (or will) do for you -- we don't normally write code from scratch, but we'll certainly help you fix an honest attempt at solving your problem.  (Don't forget `use strict; use warnings;`)

Comment: I'm sorry I was working out on the algorithm when I wrote the comment. This is how I tried, I managed to read the second table, but not very sure how to do the second one:#!/bin/env perl
` </use strict;
 use warnings;
 use autodie; 
 use Data::Dumper;
 
 # Create a file handle for the input file
 my $fname = 'secondtable.txt';
 open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $fname);
 
 # print header
 my $cname = readline $fh;
 print $cname;             # 
 
 # print rows
 while (my $line = readline $fh) {
     chomp $line;
     print "$line\n";
 }/>`

Comment: @marko: Please add information by editing your question. Code in comments us very difficult to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $file1, '<', 'in1.txt' or die $!;
open my $file2, '<', 'in2.txt' or die $!;

my %data1;
while(<$file1>){
    chomp;
    next if /^name/;
    my @split = split(/\t/);
    $data1{$split[0]}{$split[1]}++;
}

my %data2;
while(<$file2>){
    chomp;
    next if /^name/;
    my @split = split(/\t/);
    $data2{$split[0]}{$split[1]}++;
    print "$split[0]\t$split[1]\n" if $data1{$split[0]}{$split[1]};
}
```

--- in1 ---

```
name    id
foo 1
bar 2
baz 3
other   4
```

--- in2 ---

```
name    id
bar 1
baz 2
baz 3
other   4
```