# Comparing two text files and printing out matching ids, sub_ids and timestamp related to the id

Tags: perl

I'm trying to compare two txt table files file 1.txt (lookup table) and    file2.txt (master file) and print the matching ids and two more columns   from the master file (Rev_Id and Date Released).

File 1:lookup table

```
Name                IRR ID
slic73p1hsicbxttop  99034438
c73p1avrsrldo150top 99034238
c73p1avrfusevrmtop  99034201
```

File 2:masterfile

```
Type Name               Rev ID   IRR ID   PP Group      Date Released   PP Category                              
Comp c73p1avrfusevrmtop PROD_2_5 99034201 SEG RIP Reuse 5/3/2015 6:59   Hard   
Comp c73p1avrfusevrmtop PROD_2_4 99034201 SEG RIP Reuse 4/23/2015 10:27 Hard   
Comp c73p1avrfusevrmtop PROD_2_3 99034201 SEG RIP Reuse 3/17/2015 23:51 Hard   
Comp c73p1avrfusevrmtop PROD_2_2 99034201 SEG RIP Reuse 2/1/2015 11:27  Hard
```

Expected Output: there are also other rows in the table which doesn't match

```
IRR ID   Rev ID   Date Released (date to be printed in a chronological order)
99034201 PROD_2_5 5/3/2015 6:59    
99034201 PROD_2_4 4/23/2015 10:27  
99034201 PROD_2_3 3/17/2015 23:51  
99034201 PROD_2_2 2/1/2015 11:27
```

I got my code to work finally to work: This is my code but it is doing a different job to my requirement. My requirement was to get the IRR ID from the lookup.txt and match it with c73p1avrfusevrmtop.txt (master table) and print ONLY the matching IRR ID, Rev IDs (related to that IRR ID) and the date released of the Rev IDs. But my program is simply printing all the IRR IDs, RevIDs and Date Released without matching them with the lookup table. I am not sure where the bug is in my program. This is my program:

```
#!/bin/env perl
#use warnings;
 use strict; 
 use autodie; 
 use Data::Dumper;

 my $lookup_qfn = 'lookup.txt';
 my $master_qfn = 'c73p1avrfusevrmtop.txt';

 my %ids_to_lookup;
    {
    open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $lookup_qfn);
    <$fh>;  # Header
    while (<$fh>) {
       my @fields = split();
       #print Dumper(@fields);
       ++$ids_to_lookup{$fields[0]}{$fields[1]};
    }

}
my @output;
 {
    open(my $fh, '<', $master_qfn);
    <$fh>;  # Header
     print(join("    ", "IRR ID", "Rev ID", "Date Released"), "\n");
 } 

 {
    open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $master_qfn);
    <$fh>;  # Header
    while (<$fh>) {
       my @fields = split();
       #print Dumper(@fields);
       $ids_to_lookup{$fields[1]}{$fields[3]};

        print(join("  ", @fields[3,2,7,8]), "\n");
    }
}

This is my output:
     IRR ID    Rev ID    Date Released
     99034201  PROD_2_5  2015-05-03  6:59:09
     99034201  PROD_2_4  2015-04-23  10:27:38
     99034201  PROD_2_3  2015-03-17  23:51:23
     99034201  PROD_2_2  2015-02-01  11:27:55
     99034201  PROD_2_1  2014-12-26  6:43:14
     99034201  PROD_2_0  2014-12-20  21:09:06
     **99038319  PROD_1_7  2014-12-17  21:38:19
     99038319  PROD_1_6  2014-12-04  6:24:26
     99038319  PROD_1_5  2014-11-17  8:51:49**
     99034201  POLO_2_0  2014-10-30  23:01:49
     99034201  PROD_1_3  2014-06-16  6:58:50
     99034201  PROD_1_2  2014-05-10  2:37:42
     99034201  PROD_1_1  2014-04-27  22:58:48
     99034201  PROD_1_0  2014-01-17  10:15:02
     99034201  POLO_1_1  2014-01-07  11:18:45
     99034201  POLO_1_0  2013-10-20  18:23:11
     99034201  RTL1P0_1_0  2013-06-26  11:33:03
```

I know I'm bugging you guys a lot. But I just want to learn Perl with all this hard work.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what it means is it like          this                                                                                                                        my $filename1 = 'lookup.txt';
         open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename);
       Is it like this?

Comment: @lux That should fix the warning.  And, possibly, what is wrong with your program in general.

Comment: Is that data fixed-width, whitespace-separated or tab-separated?

Comment: It is tab-separated. I feel my while loop and split function is wrong.

Comment: Why does your code split on commas `,` if the data is tab-separated?

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30337959/) is almost identical and presented in a very similar way, and the `lux` account is only two days old

Comment: That may be the reason my program is not running I guess. Thanks @Borodin I was able to print the rows using this program. I was not successful in printing the header it did not print. I'm editing my question to post that there.

Comment: I am still not able to resolve why my header is not printing using the program above. Line 28:  $ids_to_lookup{$fields[1]}{$fields[3]}; . I used the sample test data from my question now. Please any help on that is much expected.Thx

Comment: Yes I'm not using that account now.

Comment: I am just wondering if my posts are visible to everyone, I was having some problems with my browser

Comment: Why do you have multiple accounts in the first place? You must decide whether you want to be `lux`, `marko` or `rajal2` and stick with it please

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you. I think ikegami overlooked the requirement to sort the output as his solution contains no code for it

I'm assuming that the Irr-ID is sufficient to identify a record, and there can't be multiple entries with the same ID and a different name

Also, this sorts the output in chronological order as you say, even though your requested output is in *reverse* chronological order

```
#!/bin/env perl

use strict; 
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /;

use Time::Piece;

my ($filename1, $filename2) = qw/ lookup.txt c73p1avfusevrmtop.txt /;

my %ids_required;

open my $fh, '<', $filename1;
while ( <$fh> ) {
  my $irr_id = (split)[1];
  ++$ids_required{$irr_id};
}

my @rows;

open $fh, '<', $filename2;
while ( <$fh> ) {

  my ($rev_id, $irr_id) = (split)[2,3];
  next unless $ids_required{$irr_id};

  my $date_time = join ' ', m< (\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}) \s+ (\d{1,2}:\d{2}) >x;
  $date_time = Time::Piece->strptime($date_time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M');
  push @rows, [ $irr_id, $rev_id, $date_time ];
}

print join("\t", 'IRR ID', 'Rev ID', 'Date Released'), "\n";
print join("\t", @$_), "\n" for sort { $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] } @rows;
```

**output**

```
IRR ID  Rev ID  Date Released
99034201    PROD_2_2    2/1/2015 11:27
99034201    PROD_2_3    3/17/2015 23:51
99034201    PROD_2_4    4/23/2015 10:27
99034201    PROD_2_5    5/3/2015 6:59
```

Comment: Could you please share your output as to what you got after plugging in the time::piece and use open qw/ :std:encoding(UTF-8) libraries

Comment: This is the error message I'm getting:                       C:\Strawberry\perl\bin>perl newlist.pl
Error parsing time at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/Time/Piece.pm line 469, <$_[...]> line 41.

Comment: @lux: I'm afraid I posted my code far too early. Try it now

Comment: @lux: Please stop editing people's solutions in order to comment on them. If you want to comment on a solution then use a comment, or to provide more information you can edit your own question

Comment: I apologize for that.

Comment: Why do I still get that error message I copied in the code. I wish it could print it tabulated as yours. But I still couldn't print it because of the libraries

Comment: @lux: Please post a comment so that other people can see what error message you're getting. Solutions on Stack Overflow are intended to be useful to other people besides the poster of the original question. You are getting that error because your actual data is different from what you have shown. If you create files with the data from your question then there will be no errors

Comment: I like to use this program to validate my current program. Unfortunately, the libraries are not getting installed in my required directories. Is there any way I could run this program without the libraries. Is it possible to give me the traditional way of printing the expected output without the Time::Piece and open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) . I'm sure with my practice and fluency with Perl I will get the knitty-gritties of Perl and make it more friendlier to me.

Comment: How can I make the program print (Time::piece) in reverse chronological order?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict; 
use autodie;
use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /;

my $lookup_qfn = 'lookup.txt';
my $master_qfn = 'c73p1avfusevrmtop.txt';

my %ids_to_lookup;
{
    open(my $fh, '<', $lookup_qfn);
    <$fh>;  # Header
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        my @fields = split /\t/;
        ++$ids_to_lookup{$fields[0]}{$fields[1]};
    }
}

my @output;
{
    open(my $fh, '<', $master_qfn);
    <$fh>;  # Header
    print(join("\t", "IRR ID", "Rev ID", "Date Released"), "\n");
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        my @fields = split /\t/;
        next if !$ids_to_lookup{$fields[1]}{$fields[3]};

        print(join("\t", @fields[3,2,5]), "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to sort on date properly, but apart from that give this a go:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 


open my $file1, '<', 'in1.txt' or die $!;
open my $file2, '<', 'in2.txt' or die $!;

my %data;
while(<$file1>){
    chomp;
    next if /^Name/;
    my @split = split(/\s+/);
    $data{$split[0]} = $split[1];
}

my %match;
while(<$file2>){
    chomp;
    next if /^Type/;
    my @split = split;
    my ($name, $rev_id, $irr_id, $date, $time) = ($split[1], $split[2], $split[3], $split[7], $split[8]);

    push @{$match{$name}{$date}}, $rev_id, $irr_id, $time;
}

foreach my $name (keys %match){
    foreach my $date (sort {  $match{$name}{$a} cmp $match{$name}{$b}} keys $match{$name}){
        my ($rev_id, $irr_id, $time) = @{$match{$name}{$date}};
        print "$irr_id\t$rev_id\t$date\t$time\n";

     }
}
```